# What type of headset will work for my Droid X?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, headphones

I'm shopping around for a nice pair of earbuds for my Droid X since I lost my other ones, and I was curious if I could get ones with a microphone to use as a headset.

What do I need to look for to make sure they're compatible?  Are all the 4-pin 3.5mm stereo jacks alike?  If it's iPhone-compatible will it not be with the Droid (especially ones with remote volume buttons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any 4-pin 3.5 mm stereo jack should work fine for straight sound but headsets with controls are a little more difficult.  Many are proprietary.  If it claims to be universal it may work but if it's designed for Apple or Nokia it probably wont.

Basically, on a 4-pin jack it all depends on which ring the headset maps to which control.  I couldn't find a Droid X pinout diagram but I believe Motorola uses the standard layout.  [This site](http://pinoutsguide.com/pin_HeadsetsHeadphones.shtml) has a pretty comprehensive list of the different pinout mappings and a lot of them are the same but a lot are proprietary.

If in doubt, I'd look for a set advertised to work with the Droid X.

Answer (score 1):

Here in India, we have Philips branded wired handsfree kits which are designed to be used with all modern phones. Certain phones require the jack to be plugged into a supplied female/male adapter which is then plugged into the 3.5mm jack of your phone.

[This is the one](http://www.philips.co.in/c/cell-phone-accessories/shh7810_10/prd/) I'm using with my Spica (the adapter also needs to be used) after the Samsung supplied ones conked out after a year of heavy duty use. ;-)

Perhaps you could find something similar...